# Exemplo de Picker View em Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Caros amigos, como faria pra popular um objeto UIPickerView com o array simples?

exemplo:

```
var titulos = ["texto1", "texto2", "texto3", "texto4"]
```

como setar esse array em uma UIPickerView?

Comment: O procedimento é o mesmo pra uma tableView. O que você tentou?

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisar settar o *delegate* e o *datasource* do `UIPickerView` no seu viewcontroller (isso pode ser feito pelo `storyboard`)

Declarar os protocolos:

```
`class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate`
```

Ter uma variável global que contenha os títulos que serão utilizados no picker:

```
var titulosArray:NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.titulosArray = ["texto1", "texto2", "texto3", "texto4"]
}
```

E ai sim implementar os protocolos para preencher o picker:

```
// MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    // Número total de componetes na picker view
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    // Número total de itens na picker view
    return self.titulosArray.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
{
    // Título com a posição do array correspondente com a linha do picker
    return self.titulosArray[row] as NSString
}
```

E é isso. Se quiser dar uma olhada nesse exemplo funcionando é só pegar aqui:
http://github.com/xdoug/SwiftPickerView

Answer (score 0):

Será necessário implementar `UIPickerViewDelegate` e `UIPickerViewDataSource`.

Com Swift eu tento usar `extension` porque torna o código mais explícito de forma a conhecer os métodos herdados de cada classe. Também gosto de criar um `protocol` para agrupar as duas classes.

Vou exemplificar.

**Protocolo das duas classes necessárias**

```
protocol PickerProtocol: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{
    // Retorna o número de colunas
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int

    // Retorna os # elementos em cada componente
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int

    // Retorna o texto a mostrar em cada componente
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
}
```

**View Controller**

```
class ExemploViewController: UIViewController
{
    var elementos: Array<String> = [] //Array nativo de Swift

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        elementos.extend(["Texto1", "Texto2", "Texto3"])

        // Criar picker view
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        self.view.addSubview(pickerView)

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

**Implementação do Protocol**

```
// MARK: - PickerProtocol

extension ExemploViewController: PickerProtocol
{
    // Retorna o número de colunas
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Retorna os # elementos em cada componente
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return elementos.count;
    }

    // Retorna o texto a mostrar em cada componente
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
    {
        return elementos[row]
    }

    // Ao seleccionar um elemento
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        NSLog("%@", elementos[row])
    }
}
```